# Google Pub/Sub - how to receive push notification in local environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

How can I receive push notifications from the pub-sub service in my local environment? If I configure topic subscription to Push it only allows me to provide an https url. I basically want to send event data into my own endpoint which atm runs locally.

Would I need to set up the cloud function, and install some kind of SDK to call my local endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: It's a network question! PubSub push to a URL (can be an IP). So, you have to expose your local IP publicly, and then route this local entry point to your local app.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere according to the docs (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#properties_of_a_push_subscription) the url must be https with a valid certificate. It does seem like the pubsub emulator allows pushing to local ip addresses, so testing with that is possible.

Comment: Do you use PubSub or PubSub emulator?

Comment: I have not used PubSub emulator yet.

Comment: Does this [link](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#install-libraries) help you in resolving the issue?